# Powermock JUnit tests are taking more time to execute compared to normal JUnit

Tags: java, junit, powermock

we are using powermock for mocking the static methods by using the `@PrepareForTest` annotations. The test runs fine but the problem is it is taking more time to execute the test.

The code snippet is like below:

```
@PrepareForTest({ StaticClass1.class, StaticClass2.class })
```

Normally, the JUnit with out mocking the static method is taking around 2 sec time to execute but when we add `@PrepareForTest` annotation for mocking the static calls, the test is taking around a minute time to complete the execution. For one test, this is not a big impact, but we have more than 1K tests and the overall build time is taking more than 2 hrs which earlier took around 20 - 30 minutes.

**What could be the reason for the powermock taking so much of time.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instrumentation performed by powermock is not free.

Comment: If you need powermock for all your tests, you probably have serious design issues. Try to write testable code, i.e. code which doesn't need the black magic of powermock to be tested. Use dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But can you please tell me exactly like what you mean by instrumentation is not free.

Comment: Hi Nizet, I dont need powermock for all the tests. May be for around 100 tests i need to use that. But because of these tests, it is taking more time. If i remove these from test suite and run, then it is working very fast.

Comment: Then try running the powermock tests and the "normal" tests in two separate runs.

Comment: Actually when we are performing the maven build, we are running the entire tests, so there it is taking more time. Individually i can run them in seperate runs but my concern is during the build as it is taking so much of time.

Answer (score 7):

PowerMock is a tool that performs bytecode instrumentation on your generated classes. Once your classes are compiled into Java Bytecode, PowerMock comes along and modifies this generated classes. It is not possible otherwise (by using Java Proxy) to mock a private or a static method.

You should only use `@PrepareForTest` annotation only in those classes that you want to use features exclusive to PowerMock, such as mocking private or static methods.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of powermock instrumentation. I am using @PrepareForTest annoation only to mock constructor calls, private methods and static methods.

Comment: Also, in one test if i mock the static class say StaticClass1 in Test1. Now in Test2, if i want to mock the same static class then will the powermock uses seperate JVM to maintain these static calls. My concern is if i mock these static calls once for the entire suite, then it has to be reused across all the test classes where this static call mock is been used. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: @Srikanth That's a separate question. You may need to consider forking your JVM per test class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332135/207238