# Spock with DbUnit test cases slowness

Tags: unit-testing, spock, dbunit

We have implemented **Spock + Db unit** framework as a part of automated unit testing.

We have now **2000 test cases (Features) for 150 Specifications with DbUnit**.

Here, We add required entries in the DB and then test the behavior of each method.

What We have observed that it takes around 2 Hrs and 30 Mins around time to execute these test cases.

I have timestamped `setup` fixture and added time stamp in a feature method. Below are my observations:

```
allergy.dao.AllergyFormDAOSpec > Get Allergy Form STANDARD_OUT
    setup method execution started at : Fri Jan 12 19:00:42 IST 2018

allergy.dao.AllergyFormDAOSpec > API to get Allergy Form STANDARD_OUT
Feature method execution started at : Fri Jan 12 19:00:44 IST 2018
Feature method execution ended at: Fri Jan 12 19:00:45 IST 2018
Total time taken to run the one test case: 242

cleanup method execution started at : Fri Jan 12 19:00:45 IST 2018
Total time taken to run a feature method : 2531
```

Here, I have observed that it takes average 2-4 seconds to load a feature method after setup. But, Original test case execution time is less than a second.

I want to know if I can get pointers on what could be delay here ? As, 3 seconds for 2000 test cases means almost 1 Hr and 30 Min of time taken by Spock other than real feature execution.

To Summarize, We want to reduce total time taken by Spock test cases when we daily run it.

**Spec**

```java
package allergy.dao

import java.util.Date

import org.dbunit.IDatabaseTester;
import org.dbunit.ext.mssql.InsertIdentityOperation;

import allergy.AllergyForm;
import be.janbols.spock.extension.dbunit.DbUnit;
import spock.lang.Shared
import util.MasterSpec

class AllergyFormDAOSpec extends MasterSpec {
    def dao = new AllergyFormDAO();
    @Shared Date timeStart1
    @Shared Date timeEnd1

@DbUnit(configure={ IDatabaseTester it ->
    it.setUpOperation = InsertIdentityOperation.REFRESH
    it.tearDownOperation = InsertIdentityOperation.DELETE
})
def content =  {
    allergy_form(formId:99999,formName:'DummySpockForm',displayIndex:1,deleteFlag:0,is_biological:1)
    allergy_form_facilities(id:99999,formId:99999,facilityid:2)
    form_concentration(id:99999,formId:99999,name:'1:100',deleteflag:0,displayindex:1)
}

def setup(){
    timeStart1 = new Date()
    println "setup method execution started at : " +  timeStart1
}

def "API to test delete Form facility"(){
    def startTime = new Date()
    println "Feature method execution started at : " +  startTime
    given:"form Id is given"
        def formId = 99999
    when:"delete form facilities"
        def result =dao.deleteFormFacilities(null, formId)
    then:"validate result"
        (result>0)==true
        def endTime = new Date()
        println "Feature method execution ended at: " +  endTime
        println 'Total time taken to run the one test case: '+ (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())
}

def cleanup() {
    timeEnd1 = new Date()
    println "cleanup method execution started at : " +  timeEnd1

    def difference = timeEnd1.time - timeStart1.time
    println "Total time taken to run a fixture method : " + difference
}
}
```

**MasterSpec**

```java
package util

import com.ecw.dao.SqlTranslator
import catalog.Root
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.sql.DataSource

/**

 */
class MasterSpec extends Specification {

@Shared
Properties properties = new Properties()
@Shared
public DataSource dataSource
@Shared
protected xmlDataSource = [:]

static int timeCntr = 0;

//setup is to read xml file's content in xmlDataSource Hashmap
def setup(){

    //Get Running Class name without its package
    def className = this.class.name.substring(this.class.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
    def resourceAnno = specificationContext.currentFeature.featureMethod.getAnnotation(FileResource)

    if(resourceAnno != null){
        def files = resourceAnno.xmlFiles()
        def packageName = (this.class.package.name).replaceAll('\\.','/')

        for(int i=0;i< files.length;i++){
            def f = new File("src/test/resources/"+packageName+"/"+className+"/"+files[i])
            def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
            def template = engine.createTemplate(f).make(null)
            def xmlString = template.toString()

            //load the hashmap with file name as Key and its content in form of string as Value
            xmlDataSource.put(files[i].split("\\.")[0],xmlString)
        }
    }
}

def setupSpec() {
    Date timeStart = new Date()

    File propertiesFile = new File('src/test/webapps/myApp/conf/connection.properties').withInputStream {
        properties.load it
    }

    String strDBName = getPropertyValue("myApp.DBName")
    if(strDBName.indexOf('?') > -1){
        strDBName = strDBName.substring(0, strDBName.indexOf('?'))
    }
    String strServerName = getPropertyValue("myApp.DBHost");
    if(strServerName.indexOf(':') > -1){
        strServerName = strServerName.substring(0, strServerName.indexOf(':'))
    }
    String strUrl = getPropertyValue("myApp.DBUrl")
    String strPort = strUrl.substring(strUrl.lastIndexOf(':') + 1)

    //FOR MSSQL
    System.setProperty("myApp.SkipJndi", "yes")
    //dataSource = new JtdsDataSource()
    Object newObject = null;
    if(SqlTranslator.isDbSqlServer()){
        newObject = Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource").newInstance()
    } else if(SqlTranslator.isDbMySql()){
        newObject = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource").newInstance()
    }

    dataSource = (DataSource)newObject
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(strDBName)
    dataSource.setUser(getPropertyValue("myApp.DBUser"))
    dataSource.setPassword(getPropertyValue("myApp.DBPassword"))
    dataSource.setServerName(strServerName)
    dataSource.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(strPort))

}
}
```

Comment: Without any code we can only wildly speculate.

Comment: Such an unclear question from an experienced member with high reputation score is hard to believe. I would assume that you should know how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: @kriegaex: I can post the code. But, I was trying to understand Spock life cycle or if anyone has been through such experience. Let me put down the whole Specification..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze the root cause of this issue, we have did run an errand with below scenarios :

**1)**  1000 Spock test cases without any Db or mocking dependencies (PowerMock)

**Sample Code to explain the scenario:**

```
package mathOperations;

import groovy.lang.Closure
import mathOperations.Math
import spock.lang.Specification

class MathSpec extends Specification {
    def objMath =new Math()

    def "API to test addition of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.AddNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.addNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 15"
            result==15
    }

    def "API to test subrtaction of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.subtractNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.subtractNumber(a, b)
        then: "Result should be 5"
            result==5
    }

    def "API to test multiplication of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.multiplyNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.multiplyNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 50"
            result==50
    }
    def "API to test division two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.divisionNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.divisionNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 2"
            result==2
    }

    def "API to test whether given both numbers are equal - Affirmative"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=10
        when: "Math.equalNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return true"
            result==true
    }

    def "API to test whether given both numbers are equal - Negative"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=11
        when: "Math.equalNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return false"
            result==false
    }
}
```

--> It took **25.153 secs** including build time and below is the report below

[image: Spock test cases without any Db or mocking dependencies]

**2)**  1000 Spock test cases with mocking (PowerMock)

**Sample Code to explain the scenario:**

```
package mathOperations;

import groovy.lang.Closure
import mathOperations.Math
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule
import org.junit.Rule
import utils.QRCodeUtils
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*

@PrepareForTest([QRCodeUtils.class])
class MathSpec extends Specification {
    def objMath =new Math()

    @Rule PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule()

    def "API to test add two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=5
        when: "Math.AddNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.addNumber(a,b)
        then: "result should be 15"
        result==15
    }

    def "API to test subract two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=5
        when: "Math.subtractNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.subtractNumber(a, b)
        then: "result should be 5"
        result==5
    }
    def "API to test multiple two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=5
        when: "Math.multiplyNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.multiplyNumber(a,b)
        then: "result should be 50"
        result==50
    }
    def "API to test divide two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=5
        when: "Math.divisionNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.divisionNumber(a,b)
        then: "result should be 2"
        result==2
    }
    def "API to test modulo of a number"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=5
        when: "Math.moduloNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.moduloNumber(a,b)
        then: "result should be 0"
        result==0
    }

    def "API to test power of a number"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=2
        when: "Math.powerofNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.powerofNumber(a,b)
        then: "result should be 0"
        result==8
    }

    def "API to test numbers are equal -affirmative"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=10
        when: "Math.equalNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return true"
        result==true
    }

    def "API to test numbers are equal -negative"() {
        given :"a and b"
        def a=10
        def b=11
        when: "Math.equalNumber is call with given values"
        mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(5)
        def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return false"
        result==false
    }

    void mockGetOTPAttemptStatus(int status) {
        mockStatic(QRCodeUtils.class)
        when(QRCodeUtils.getOTPAttemptStatus(anyInt())).thenReturn(status)
    }
}
```

-->  It took **9 mins 14.222 secs** including build time and below is the report

[image: Spock test cases with mocking]

**3)**  1000 Spock test cases with only Dbunit. (Usually, We insert average 15-20 table entries in a test case. Here, We added the same)

**Sample Code to explain the scenario:**

```
package mathOperations;

import groovy.lang.Closure
import java.sql.Statement
import mathOperations.Math
import spock.lang.Shared
import util.BaseSpec
import catalog.Root
import spock.lang.Ignore
import org.dbunit.ext.mssql.InsertIdentityOperation
import be.janbols.spock.extension.dbunit.DbUnit
import org.dbunit.IDatabaseTester

class MathSpec extends BaseSpec {

    @Shared root
    def objMath =new Math()

    @DbUnit(configure={
        IDatabaseTester it ->
        it.setUpOperation = InsertIdentityOperation.REFRESH
        it.tearDownOperation = InsertIdentityOperation.DELETE
    })
    def content =  {
        table1(id:99,MasterFile:'UnitTestFile',DataElementName:'test',DataElementDBColName:'TestDbCol',DataElementTableName:'TestTable')
        table2(id:99,MasterFile:'UnitTestFile',DataElementName:'test',DataElementDBColName:'TestDbCol',DataElementTableName:'TestTable')
        table3(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table4(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table5(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table6(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table7(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table8(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table9(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
        table10(id:99,Code:'T00.0',Status:'A',LongDesc:'Unit Testing')
    }

    def "API to test addition of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.AddNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.addNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 15"
            result==15
    }

    def "API to test subrtaction of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.subtractNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.subtractNumber(a, b)
        then: "Result should be 5"
            result==5
    }

    def "API to test multiplication of two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.multiplyNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.multiplyNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 50"
            result==50
    }
    def "API to test division two numbers"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=5
        when: "Math.divisionNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.divisionNumber(a,b)
        then: "Result should be 2"
            result==2
    }

    def "API to test whether given both numbers are equal - Affirmative"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=10
        when: "Math.equalNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return true"
            result==true
    }

    def "API to test whether given both numbers are equal - Negative"() {
        given :"a and b"
            def a=10
            def b=11
        when: "Math.equalNumber is called with given values"
            def result =objMath.equalNumber(a,b)
        then: "It should return false"
            result==false
    }
}
```

--> It took **57 mins 18.136 secs** including build time and below is the report
[image: Spock test cases with only Dbunit]

We have drawn a conclusion that Spock does not take time to run test cases but Power Mock which does instrumentation [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846183/powermock-junit-tests-are-taking-more-time-to-execute-compared-to-normal-junit) and DbUnit (Loads everything using reflection) were bottlenecks.

**Solution:** 
We are going with in house framework to insert/delete database data instead of DbUnit. Also, We have replaced Power Mock with [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/api1x/mockit/MockUp.html)

**End Result:** As I did post in the question total time from 2 **Hrs and 30 Mins**, has been now reduced to **6 Minutes** for these **1000** test cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is indeed too broad and doesn't provide enough information to give a qualified answer. However, I can say that Spock itself is supposed to be really fast (not as fast as a 'raw' JUnit, it's still groovy after all, but really fast enough for tests).

From your question, it looks like you suspect Spock to be a bottleneck, so,
for example, you could place an empty Spock test and measure its execution right next to your DbUnit enabled tests, I can assure you that the times you'll get will be negligible.

So I believe the reason is that during the setup/cleanup, the DbUnit calls some database related code (probably schema generation/tables population and/or removal) and it takes a lot of time. So my second attempt would be just printing the SQL queries that run during the test, probably you'll reveal that many of them run during the setup method.

Another possible reason is that for doing tests there is just too much data that gets inserted before the test.

And yet another possible reason is that the database you're running the tests against is just too slow (slow network, the db itself is way too busy).

Now what are solutions to all this? :) You might want to take a look on Spring's approach to test the Data Access Layer + how to do an initial setup. Since it's far beyond the scope of the question, I won't talk too much about spring here, but just as an idea:

- Generate the data once
- Insert it before all tests run
- With the beginning of the test start a transaction
- Rollback a transaction when the test finishes (even if the test succeeds), this way the data won't be preserved. If you work with Isolation and the database server supports it, you can run even tests in parallel, no problem with that.

If the reason for slowness is a database server, then (besides obvious suggestions like "change your RDBMS") you can try to run a database in docker in the same machine/or even start a database before your tests start locally using [TestContainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java).

Comment: We had tried with out DbUnit test cases also. Still, It takes time to run feature method after setup. Also, It happens for all Specifications. I have added some code

Comment: Could you measure Master spec's setup and setupSpec execution times as well? Probably they'll point/be themselves a core reason of slowness? In general setup/setupSpec are just like @Before/@BeforeClass in JUnit, nothing really special about it, maybe besides the fact that setupSpec is not static unlike its JUnit counterpart...

Comment: We did its not adding much difference. But, It looks like Spock is not the bottleneck here. We are looking into our Mocking and DbUnit implementations

Comment: We noticed that if we remove "@PrepareForTest" annotations all test cases starts running in the half time. I will post my analysis. I found your answer more near to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually quite simple: You forgot to measure the master spec's setup time. Maybe you are assuming that a `setup()` method in a child spec overrides its parent spec's `setup()` method. But in Spock it does not! All of

- `setupSpec()`
- `setup()`
- `cleanup()`
- `cleanupSpec()`

of all specs along the class hierarchy will be executed in the order: base class first, then child class.

Let me show you with a primitive example what I am talking about:

**Master spec:**

Why a thread-local static variable? Well, maybe you are running your tests concurrently. For this simple example it would not have been necessary.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification
import static System.currentTimeMillis

class MasterSpec extends Specification {
  static ThreadLocal<Long> startMillis = new ThreadLocal<>()

  def setupSpec() {
    startMillis.set(currentTimeMillis())
    sleep 50
    println "BaseSpec.setupSpec: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def cleanupSpec() {
    sleep 50
    println "BaseSpec.cleanupSpec: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def setup() {
    sleep 50
    println "BaseSpec.setup: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def cleanup() {
    sleep 50
    println "BaseSpec.cleanup: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }
}
```

**Derived spec:**

Why the name `DerivedTest`? Just because my Maven build is configured in a way to find tests based on default names `*Test` (Surefire unit tests) or `*IT` (Failsafe integration tests).

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Unroll

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis

class DerivedTest extends MasterSpec {
  def setupSpec() {
    sleep 50
    println "DerivedTest.setupSpec: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def cleanupSpec() {
    sleep 50
    println "DerivedTest.cleanupSpec: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def setup() {
    sleep 50
    println "DerivedTest.setup: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  def cleanup() {
    sleep 50
    println "DerivedTest.cleanup: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())
  }

  @Unroll
  def "feature #id"() {
    given:
    long featureStartMillis = currentTimeMillis()
    sleep 50
    println "DerivedTest.feature $id: " + (currentTimeMillis() - startMillis.get())

    expect:
    true

    cleanup:
    println "DerivedTest.feature $id ONLY: " + (currentTimeMillis() - featureStartMillis)

    where:
    id << ["A", "B"]
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
BaseSpec.setupSpec: 105
DerivedTest.setupSpec: 193
BaseSpec.setup: 286
DerivedTest.setup: 336
DerivedTest.feature A: 396
DerivedTest.feature A ONLY: 55
DerivedTest.cleanup: 453
BaseSpec.cleanup: 504
BaseSpec.setup: 556
DerivedTest.setup: 606
DerivedTest.feature B: 656
DerivedTest.feature B ONLY: 50
DerivedTest.cleanup: 706
BaseSpec.cleanup: 757
DerivedTest.cleanupSpec: 808
BaseSpec.cleanupSpec: 858
```

Can you see the order of execution and also the time consumed by each step?

I would say, your complex operations in the master spec (reading config files, initialising and filling database etc.)

Comment: we are using powermock for mocking the static methods by using the @PrepareForTest annotations.  Could it be also one of the bottle necks ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846183/powermock-junit-tests-are-taking-more-time-to-execute-compared-to-normal-junit

Comment: Maybe, but probably not. I have used Powermock before in connection with Spock, but never noticed any performance issues there. I do not use PM anymore though because if you do use it it is a smell and a sure sign that you should refactor your code in order to make it testable. Other than that, I cannot believe that you seem to ignore my explanation for your problem and are still looking for problems elsewhere. The problem sits in front of the keyboard! Please read my analysis and sample code again and compare with your own code. It is pretty obvious that it is your code making the tests slow.

Comment: Update: I have just opened one of my old Powermock tests and added timing statements. The average time for a spec using `@PrepareForTest` + `@Rule PowerMockRule` in between end of `setup()` and beginning of feature method is 290 ms on my laptop, i.e. the delay is noticeable but nowhere near 2 seconds. I suggest you clone your test and comment out more and more code parts until you see where the time gets lost.

Comment: We noticed that if we remove "@PrepareForTest" annotations all test cases starts running in the half time. I will post my analysis. For now, We have changed Mocking to jMockito as we need to mock private and static methods. Appreciate your time and answer

Comment: I do not know jMockito. Nice to learn that it is faster for you, though. For statics I use PowerMock (well, or rather I refactor), for privates Spock is enough, no need to use additional tools. For final classes and methods you can also either use PowerMock, but have to use its assertions then, or use a [special test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48402178/1082681) which enables you to just continue to work with Spock's normal mocks, stubs and spies.

Comment: Yes, We were already using PowerMock for  final classes and methods. We don't have bandwidth for now to refactor the code.

Comment: I am still curious because on SO I also want to learn, not only teach. So I searched but found nothing about any tool named _jMockito_. Is it possible that you are talking about _JMockit_ instead?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, its JMockit (My bad it was typo). I have added sample code analysis.

Comment: One more remark, if I may: The statement "we don't have bandwidth for now to refactor the code" is like saying "we have no time for sharpening our saw, we need to cut trees", even though the "no bandwidth" problem actually originates in your being unwilling to refactor. Testability is of paramount importance for quality code and stable software. Taking no time to do that means that you are not what I would call a developer. No offense meant, but this is my opinion.